If יהּ is a distinct name, can אהיה be parsed both as א ה יה, I-the-JAH and I AM, א היה?
The name of God is most often written as YHVH, יהוה. Sometimes it is written as YH, יהּ.
Exodus 15

1 Then Moses and the people of Israel sang this song to the LORD יהוה, saying, “I will sing to the LORD, for he has triumphed gloriously; the horse and his rider he has thrown into the sea. 2 The LORD יהּ is my strength and my song, and he has become my salvation... (ESV)


1 Then singeth Moses and the sons of Israel this song to Jehovah יהוה, and they speak, saying: -- `I sing to Jehovah יהוה, For triumphing He hath triumphed; The horse and its rider He hath thrown into the sea. 2 My strength and song is Jah יהּ, And He is become my salvation... (YLT)

Translations like the ESV consider יהּ an abbreviation of יהוה treating both as LORD. Others like Young's understand a distinction and translate each differently: Jehovah and Jah.
If יהּ is a distinct name, can אהיה be parsed both as א ה יה, I-the-JAH and I AM, א היה?
Exodus 3:14

God said to Moses, “I the YAH who I AM.”


Proper names (including the Tetragrammaton) don't get a definite article in Hebrew, this kind of reading is foreign to Hebrew

@AviAvraham הנּה־קול שׁועת בּת־עמּי מארץ מרחקּים היהוה אין בּציּון אם־מלכּהּ אין בּהּ מדּוּע הכעסוּני בּפסליהם בּהבלי נכר Jeremiah 8:19. Isn't this an example of the article used with the Tetragrammaton?

nope, that's an interrogative marker which makes that verse a rhetorical question: "Is not Hashem in Żiyyon?"

@AviAvraham And impossible for a similar interrogative understanding for one of the two in Exodus? IOW rather than repeating the name, "I will be who I Yah will be." Say to them "I will be" sent me.

No, there's still no plausible reading of either passage which would involve splitting אהיה the way you've proposed. An interrogative here would make no sense. There's no reason to split אהיה any more than there is to split אשר to mean "I am a prince"

@AviAvraham Thank you. Not sure I would agree with the position there is no reason to split the meaning. We are considering a name given personally and once to Moses. After crossing the Red Sea Moses sings to YH. Given what was said at the burning bush, it seems like Moses understood YH from that encounter. Splitting makes sense by making clear something unique not previously or otherwise explained,

No.  The use of "הָיָה" at Exodus 3:14 is a verb, "hayah" (Strong's H1961).  It is not parsed into two pieces.  The reference under BDB definition III as "exist, or be" references Strong's H3068, "יהוֺה" which is the proper name of YHVH, Jehovah.  The short version of His name is Strong's 3050, "יָהּ" or "Yah" as used in Ex. 15:2.
Just as we might shorten a proper name such as Robert to Rob or Joshua to Josh, Yah is the first half of YHVH.  The Jehovah spelling of YHVH should be sounded Yahoowah, and is the English introduced by Tynsdale's phonetic pronunciation of the Hebrew YHVH, Yah oo wah.  The English "J" was invented to distinguish it from the Greek and Latin "ia" sound of "yah".  The original "V" or "vav" was sounded as a long "oooo" sound as in "rule."
Both H3068, and H3050 are defined as the proper name of God.  Verbs are not contracted into short versions, but proper names often are.
People incorrectly say "yahway" for YHVH, but it is "ee yah ooo wah", the four Hebrew vowel sounds which Josephus referred to on the breast plate of the high priest.  (Source: Gutenberg, "in which was engraven the sacred name [of God]: it consists of four vowels" 5.5.7)
There is more confirmation of the pronunciation as "Yah ooo wah" from the Egyptian hieroglyphics "yh" or "yhw" found at some of the temples of Thutmosis III, Amenhotep II, Thutmosis IV, Amenhotep III, Akenaton, Seti I, Ramses II, Merneptah, and Rameses III.  Those hieroglyphics were pronounced as "yah" and "yah ooo wah."  (See my post The Name of God)
So if you parse "יהוֺה" it would be "yah" and "ooowah" which is not the meaning at Ex. 3:14 of continual existence.

Do you find it odd that a people who won't pronounce the name or write it, would abbreviate it? Yes we might call Robert, Bob, but would a human dare to take that liberty with the personal name of God?

I do have some reservations about it, but it is used in scripture in several places as you pointed out.  So, when I call upon Him in prayer, I always say "Father in heaven".  But if I am writing I usually use YHVH.
